# Hide my Socket Constructor to hide IP and PORT

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm currently programming a chat application for Android and I am in a important issue. I want to my Client Programs to connect to my Server which is easy by creating a Socket, the thing is what anyone who can see my source code can know the IP and PORT of my Server, which will allow they to send data (or packets) what my Server can receive and do things with it and it won't know what the sender is a unknown program.

The question is how I can hide IP or Port of the Socket Code so only my apps will know what's the IP and Port of the Server, is there any method? a security process?

Comment: It's called obfuscation, and it usually not worth too much effort. In your case it would be completely worthless because no matter how well obfuscated your code is anyone with a network sniffer can observe the port and IP address in network traffic.

Comment: i know about obfuscation but it can be evaded some how, im almost sure what there is a way to hide it, or i will able to even see facebook or twitter server IPS (ill take time but its stilk possible i guess). maybe i think some security protocols but i really dont know anyone who can prevent sending information to server from unknown programa